# PHP Headers and downloads

Tags: php, apache, header, download

I am currently trying to develop a PHP application in which my server downloads a file and the user can do the same almost simultaneously. I already think about the problem "If the user downloads fastly than the server...", but it's not a problem at this moment.
To do so, I used the header and readfile functions of php. Here is my code :

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$data['name'].'";'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
header('Content-Length: '.$data['size']);
readfile($remoteFile);
```

I must to use the Content-length header to set the proper size of the file and not the size that is downloaded when the user clicks on the link. However, after some seconds or minutes, download is stopped and I need to restart...
If you think about a solution, even if it didn't use the header(); function, please tell me.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: What is the file size? Are you on localhost or real server machine?

Comment: Your script is probably timing out on your server (or getting kicked per your hosting company).

Comment: I can have some large file (> 500 Mb), and it is on a real and dedicated server. I try to set the max_php_execution_time to 0 on php.ini, but it doesn't work, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced that this is directly related to maximum runtime settings, that are enforced upon you if you run with safe_mode on.

If you have the option, try setting `set_time_limit(0)` and see if that makes it work.

if you have your own server, you should look into the [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) module for apache, since that is built specifically to send large files to the user.

Oh, and its stupidly easy to use

```
header("X-Sendfile: $path_to_somefile");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$somefile\"");
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work... It downloads empty file (0 byte), even if i set "Content-length", in header, weird...